# How does the SPF multiple requirements example work?

Tags: rfc, spf

The [SPF RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208) contains a [complex example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#appendix-A.4) at the end that confused me.

```
A.4.  Multiple Requirements Example

   Say that your sender policy requires both that the IP address is
   within a certain range and that the reverse DNS for the IP matches.
   This can be done several ways, including the following:

   example.com.           SPF  ( "v=spf1 "
                                 "-include:ip4._spf.%{d} "
                                 "-include:ptr._spf.%{d} "
                                 "+all" )
   ip4._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ip4:192.0.2.0/24 +all"
   ptr._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ptr +all"

   This example shows how the "-include" mechanism can be useful, how an
   SPF record that ends in "+all" can be very restrictive, and the use
   of De Morgan's Law.
```

If an IP address fails the two include patterns, isn't it accepted by the last `+all`?

Answer (score 0):

*Short version:* The include mechanism matches only if the included test passes. The algorithm stops on a match and returns fail in that example.

*Long version:*
In order to understand this example, you need to know when the algorithm stops. It stops and returns a result at any match. Let's look at a slightly different example without include mechanisms:

```
v=spf1 +mx +ip4:192.0.2.0/24 -all
```

It says: If the IP address has an MX record or is in the given IP range, then pass, otherwise fail. If the tested host has an MX record, the algorithm will stop at that match and not check the IP range. The `-all` is not reached.

This way of writing SPF records allows to define multiple conditions that act like whitelists and blacklists. And the first match wins.

The include mechanism works a bit different. The included SPF record returns a result, for example pass or fail. And that result determines if the include mechanism is a match or not. The [include specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) says that it only matches if it returns a pass. Now let's look at the example again:

```
   example.com.           SPF  ( "v=spf1 "
                                 "-include:ip4._spf.%{d} "
                                 "-include:ptr._spf.%{d} "
                                 "+all" )
   ip4._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ip4:192.0.2.0/24 +all"
   ptr._spf.example.com.  SPF  "v=spf1 -ptr +all"
```

If the tested host has the IP address `10.0.0.1`, the first included record `v=spf1 -ip4:192.0.2.0/24 +all` gives a pass. That means that the include is a match and processing stops. The `-` qualifier before the include makes the including record fail. That host is not allowed to send.

If the tested host has the IP address `192.0.2.1`, it will match `-ip4:192.0.2.0/24`. This makes the first included record fail. But a fail result means that the include mechanism says: "not match". The algorithm will continue to the second include mechanism. The included record will fail as well which means it doesn't match again. Finally, the `+all` is reached and returns a pass. This host is allowed to send.

So failing includes are a way of inverting tests and requiring a host to pass (not match) multiple tests.